# Looking to recreate the customizable forecasting page

Tags: apex, visualforce, forecast

I'm looking for some ideas on how to recreate the customizable forecasting page with a few additional columns.
The out-of-the-box forecasting page doesn't allow you to alter any column names or add additional columns.
Has any one here attempted this?
If so, I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions, tips or better yet "this is how you do it". :)

Thanks.

Comment: Consider jQuery tables... something along the lines of the DataTables plugin (datatables.net). This approach yields a very nice user experience and can be configured to support dynamic table filtering-as-you-type, a very useful feature when viewing many rows of Opportunities.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into jQuery tables and post back my  results.

Comment: JQuery datatables worked great. Took a little time to familiarize myself with framework however, everything is working great and looks fantastic. Thank you for the suggestion.